# Coefficients of model and liklihood ratio test

Tags: regression, likelihood-ratio, model-comparison

I ran a regression on some data I collected.  The data has one independent variable and looks as if a quadratic function would fit it well.

I fit both a quadratic and a quartic model to the data and performed a likelihood ratio test. Seems that I should prefer the quartic model (p<0.001).

However, the coefficients of my quartic model are not statistically significant.

Should I prefer the quadratic model because it's coefficients are statistically significant, or prefer the quartic model from the results of the liklihood ratio test?

Comment: Why do you think the likelihood ratio test is telling you the quartic is better and not that the quadratic is better?

Comment: @SalMangiafico It can probably fit the data better and thus have smaller RSS

Comment: I mean, are you looking at which model had a higher likelihood or a lower RSS? People often compare models using  the AIC or BIC, or perhaps the adjusted r-squared.